# Text formating - sed, awk, shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I need some assistance trying to build up a variable using a list of exclusions in a file.

So I have a exclude file I am using for rsync that looks like this:

```
*.log
*.out
*.csv
logs
shared
tracing
jdk*
8.6_Code
rpsupport
dbarchive
inarchive
comms
PR116PICL
**/lost+found*/
dlxwhsr*
regression
tmp
working
investigation
Investigation
dcsserver_weblogic_
dcswebrdtEAR_weblogic_
```

I need to build up a string to be used as a variable to feed into egrep -v, so that I can use the same exclusion list for rsync as I do when egrep -v from a find -ls.

So I have created this so far to remove all "*" and "/" - and then when it sees certain special characters it escapes them:

```
cat exclude-list.supt | while read line
    do
    echo $line | sed 's/\*//g' | sed 's/\///g' | 's/\([.-+_]\)/\\\1/g'
```

What I need the ouput too look like is this and then export that as a variable:

```
SEXCLUDE_supt="\.log|\.out|\.csv|logs|shared|PR116PICL|tracing|lost\+found|jdk|8\.6\_Code|rpsupport|dbarchive|inarchive|comms|dlxwhsr|regression|tmp|working|investigation|Investigation|dcsserver\_weblogic\_|dcswebrdtEAR\_weblogic\_"
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues with the following:

```
cat exclude-list.supt | while read line
    do
    echo $line | sed 's/\*//g' | sed 's/\///g' | 's/\([.-+_]\)/\\\1/g'
```

`Sed` reads files line by line so `cat | while read line;do echo $line | sed` is completely redundant also `sed` can do multiple substitutions by either passing them as a comma separated list or using the `-e` option so piping to `sed` three times is two too many. A problem with '[.-+_]' is the `-` is between `.` and `+` so it's interpreted as a range `.-+` when using `-` inside a character class put it at the end beginning or end to lose this meaning like `[._+-]`.

A much better way:

```
$ sed -e 's/[*/]//g' -e 's/\([._+-]\)/\\\1/g' file
\.log
\.out
\.csv
logs
shared
tracing
jdk
8\.6\_Code
rpsupport
dbarchive
inarchive
comms
PR116PICL
lost\+found
dlxwhsr
regression
tmp
working
investigation
Investigation
dcsserver\_weblogic\_
dcswebrdtEAR\_weblogic\_
```

Now we can pipe through `tr '\n' '|'` to replace the newlines with pipes for the alternation ready for `egrep`:

```
$ sed -e 's/[*/]//g' -e 's/\([._+-]\)/\\\1/g' file | tr "\n" "|"
\.log|\.out|\.csv|logs|shared|tracing|jdk|8\.6\_Code|rpsupport|dbarchive|...

$ EXCLUDE=$(sed -e 's/[*/]//g' -e 's/\([._+-]\)/\\\1/g' file | tr "\n" "|")

$ echo $EXCLUDE
\.log|\.out|\.csv|logs|shared|tracing|jdk|8\.6\_Code|rpsupport|dbarchive|...
```

Note: If your file ends with a newline character you will want to remove the final trailing `|`, try `sed 's/\(.*\)|/\1/'`.

Comment: sudo_O you are a legend this is perfect and works a treat... I have certainly learned a thing or 2 here... thanks so much for making the time to answer and explain!!!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
SEXCLUDE_supt=$(sed '1h;1!H;$!d;g;s/[*\/]//g;s/\([.-+_]\)/\\\1/g;s/\n/|/g' file)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work but I guess there are better solutions. First store everything in a bash array:

```
SEXCLUDE_supt=$( sed -e 's/\*//g' -e 's/\///g' -e 's/\([.-+_]\)/\\\1/g' exclude-list.supt)
```

and then process it again to substitute white space:

```
SEXCLUDE_supt=$(echo $SEXCLUDE_supt |sed 's/\s/|/g')
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. `sed 's/\s/|/g'` doesnt do what you think and you have retained some mistake from the OP.

Comment: I tried it out and it was substituting the white spaces..
I did not know about the position of the "-" in [.-+_] though.

Comment: Anyway, what I posted gave me exactly the same output as your script, apart for the final trailing `|`. So why is `sed 's/\s/|/g'` wrong?

Comment: I just realised you are relying on the shell to flatten the file not `sed`.